# Memory Access Violation on appending a QLinkedList (C++ with Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, memory, crash

So I’ve written a MainWindow that starts a few things, one of which is a server that handles connections in another thread. It’s basically a peer to peer instant message client over TCP. I haven’t really been able to test that it’s working correctly because I’m getting a memory access violation when appending text to my QLinkedList of data items. The underlying threads have access to this list and on a timer scan the list to find the data that still needs to be sent over that socket. In the main window, when the user clicks the pushbutton the text that is in the box should be appended into that list of data to be sent by the sockets. However, every time I attempt to append something, I get a memory access violation error. I’ve been trying to debug this for hours stepping through with Visual Studio and I am now looking for a fresh set of eyes.

Here’s my MainWindow class implementation:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
   : QMainWindow(parent),
   , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    timer = new QTimer;
    sysFrame = new int;
    data = new QLinkedList<Data>;
    timer->start(500);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout(QPrivateSignal)),this,SLOT(handleTime()));
    *sysFrame =0;
    addr = new QString;
    msgs = new QString;
    lock = new QMutex;
    name = new QString;
    startDialog start(name,addr);
    start.setModal(true);
    start.exec();
    Server serv(sysFrame,data,lock,*addr,msgs);
    serv.StartServer();
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete sysFrame;
    delete timer;
    delete addr;
    delete data;
    delete msgs;
    delete lock;
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Data tempData;
    QString tempString;
    tempString.clear();
    tempString.append("<").append(name).append(">: ");
    tempString.append(ui->lineEdit->text());
    ui->lineEdit->clear();
    lock->lock();
    tempData.frame=*sysFrame;
    tempData.text=tempString;
    data->append(tempData); //Memory access violation here.
    msgs->append(tempString);
    msgs->append("\n");
    lock->unlock();
}

void MainWindow::handleTime()
{
    ui->textBrowser->clear();
    ui->textBrowser->setText(*msgs);
    ui->textBrowser->repaint();
}
```

The memory issue is commented, and is in the "on_pushButton_clicked" method.

I'm really trying to get this error figured out so I can continue debugging my code.

Thanks.

Data class:

```
#include <QObject>

class Data : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
Data(QObject *parent=0);
~Data();
QString text;
int frame;

private:

};
```

Comment: Show the declaration of type `Data`

Comment: BTW, `Server serv(...` is created in stack and will be destroyed when c-tor will end. Is it what you want?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that Server would be destroyed. I didn't think about it and I'll make it on the heap.

Comment: @borisbn I've added the Data class to the original post.

Comment: You are dynamically allocating all MainWindow's member variables, even the integer. I suggest that don't do that. Instead of e.g. `int* sysFrame`, use `int sysFrame` and instead of `QString* addr` just use `QString addr`. Then you don't need to new and delete all those variables by yourself. Also, are you sure the QLinkedList is the container class you really need? I have used Qt quite a lot, but I have never needed QLinkedList. From QLinkedList's documentation: "For most purposes, QList is the right class to use."

Comment: If your Data class is just a container for one string and one int and you are never going to use signals and slots with it, then you don't need to derive it from QObject.

Comment: I can't see any problem **with QLinkedList** in the code. Make a minimal (!!!) test that represents access violation